Extract embedded pdf with wordpress cookies using cURL / XHR
I'm trying to use cURL to extract an embedded PDF located at site that requires a username/password login (wordpress cookie). The actual file is located here, and the login is located here.
I was trying to follow steps here and here but am still getting a broken PDF as a result.  Here's what I've tried:

Get cURL command to log into server

Load login page for website and open Network pane of Developer Tools
In firefox, right click page, choose 'Inspect Element (Q)' and click
on Network tab
Go to login form, enter username, password and log in
After you have logged in, go back to Network pane and scroll to the
top to find the POST entry.
Right click and choose Copy -> Copy as CURL
Paste this to a text editor


Save session cookie:

Using the pasted info from #1, remove the entry -H 'Cookie: <somestuff>'
Insert -curl -c login_cookie.txt to the beginning and run the code
this saves 'login_cookie.txt' to the folder
*the issue I have at this point is login_cookie.txt does not appear to have worked. When opening up the .txt file, I'm seeing "fakesessid" and a lot of FALSE & TRUE messages in the .txt file that I can't figure out


Get cURL command to the actual PDF

go to the actual webpage where the PDF is located
inspect element, go to Network tab, look for the XHR file (size is ~equal to the size of PDF I want downloaded)
Right click and choose Copy -> Copy as CURL
paste this into text editor
remove the entry -H 'Cookie: <somestuff>'
Insert -curl -b login_cookie.txt to the beginning
Insert --output filename.pdf to the end and run code
*At this point of the process, I do see a PDF downloaded, but the PDF is corrupt.



What am I doing wrong? My exact codes (less password info located below):
Code to save login cookies:
curl -c login_cookie.txt 'https://fddexchange.com/wp-login.php' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'origin: https://fddexchange.com' \
  -H 'priority: u=0, i' \
  -H 'referer: https://fddexchange.com/login-2/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw 'pmpro_login_form_used=1&log=REDACTEDUSERNAME&pwd=REDACTEDPWORD&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to='

Code to download PDF:
curl 'https://fddexchange.com/?title=Dogtopia%20Complete%20FDD%20April%2015%202024&index=1&pdfID=86513&pdfemb-serveurl=https%3A%2F%2Ffddexchange.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsecurepdfs%2F2024%2F05%2FDogtopia-Complete-FDD-April-15-2024.pdf&pdfemb-nonce=baee332b39' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: https://fddexchange.com/?title=Dogtopia%20Complete%20FDD%20April%2015%202024&index=1&pdfID=86513&pdfemb-serveurl=https%3A%2F%2Ffddexchange.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsecurepdfs%2F2024%2F05%2FDogtopia-Complete-FDD-April-15-2024.pdf' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36' 


It’s possible the file you save as a .pdf actually contains the HTML of an error-message page. Does it? If so, please [edit] your question to explain the error it shows.

when i change the .pdf extension to html, I get unrecognizable characters
